# Python: Search in an online CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am currently stuck with a Python project where I want to get the information out of an online CSV file and want to let the user search via an input function. At the moment, I am able to get the information from the online CSV file via a link but I cannot make the connection so that it searches the exact word in that CSV file.

I currently have tried multiple tutorials but most of them aren't solving my issue. So with a lot of pain, I am writing this message here, hoping someone can help me out.

The code I have so far is:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

metar_search = input('Enter the ICAO station\n')

url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.csv'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
cr = csv.reader(lines)

for row in cr:
    if metar_search == row[0]:
        print(row)
```

In the CSV file, the first row is what I am looking for. It is the METAR information of an airport. So, I want the user to type the ICAO code (*for example KJFK*), then I want the line of text the weather information of that station (*example: KJFK 051851Z 15010KT 10SM FEW017 FEW035 FEW250 27/19 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP177 T02670194*).
When I currently type KJFk, it is not returning any information back.

The current code is probably a bit messy because I have tried several things, I also tried to make a function of it but without luck. What am I doing wrong?

I hope someone is able to help me out with this question.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
...
for row in cr:
    if row[0].startswith(metar_search):
        print(row)
```

or

```
...
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()[5:]]
cr = csv.reader(lines)

for row in cr:
    if metar_search == row[1]:
        print(row)
```

Hint: Take a closer look at the data.

If you know that there's only one result then you could stop searching after you found the row:

```
...
        print(row)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast help! Both of your solutions are working! I really appreciate you for helping me out, thank you.